# Unable to create database runtime when i create a install form in codeigniter version 3.0.6

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create CodeIgniter-Installer method, when i run application for first time  database should be created dynamically. I have the below code, its work well in codeigniter version 2.2.0 , but get error in version 3.0. Error is " mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database ".

$this->load->database($config_db); is not working

```
if(!is_array($config_db))
    {
        $config_db = array();
        $config_db['hostname'] = $this->input->post('host');
        $config_db['username'] = $this->input->post('user');
        $config_db['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
        $config_db['database'] = $this->input->post('database');
        $config_db['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';   

    }
    // Unset any existing DB information
    unset($this->db);

    // Explicitly set debugging to FALSE to avoid CI throwing errors if its wrong
    $config_db['db_debug'] = FALSE;

    // load based on custom passed information
    $this->load->database($config_db);

    if (is_resource($this->db->conn_id) OR is_object($this->db->conn_id))
    {
        // There is a connection

        $this->load->dbutil();

        // Now then, does the DB exist?
        if ($this->dbutil->database_exists($this->db->database))
        {
            // Connected and found the db. Happy days are here again!
            return TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->dbforge();

            if ($this->dbforge->create_database($this->db->database))
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: i think u need to use `mysqli` here `$config_db['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: u r changing the database as per form input??

Comment: i have tried mysqli also, but i got same error. yes i am "creating database" by form input

Comment: `$config_db['db_debug'] = FALSE;` ->  `$config_db['db_debug'] = TRUE;`, might help finding a solution.

Comment: Hi Phiter , i have tried , but i still get same error                                        A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'abd'
Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php
Line Number: 203
Backtrace:
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cmgv\application\controllers\install.php
Line: 191
Function: database
Function: require_once Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/cmgv/system/database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 436

Comment: hard code the database name, u will get the idea.

Comment: Hi devpro, i also tried hard coded.   $this->load->dbforge();
    if ($this->dbforge->create_database('abc')

Comment: i am talking about `$config_db['database'] = "yourDBName"`;

Comment: or plz share 'print_r($_POST)'; what are u getting in this?

Comment: print_r($_POST); gets Array ( [host] => localhost [database] => abdcc [user] => root [password] => root [admin_email] => admin@gmail.com [admin_password] => admin [submit] => Install )                                               print_r($config_db); gets Array ( [hostname] => localhost [username] => root [password] => root [database] => abdcc [dbdriver] => mysqli [db_debug] => 1)

Comment: password = root is correct? did u grant access to root?

Comment: i think should be empty, for localhost, password field should be empty.

Comment: yes my phpmyadmin password is 'root'